# Recursive function not iterating variable as expected

Tags: php, loops, foreach, iteration

I'm currently rewriting a navigation structure to be sorted by size into multiple columns, when I encountered some unexpected behavior, which I've successfully recreated here.

I'm creating an array with several items, also arrays. the items contain a name and might contain an array `sub` which is an array of more items. This has the possibility to be nested into infinity.
The list will be displayed in HTML as a multiple layered `ul`.
Using a recusive function would make sense in this case. As mentioned before the list will be sorted by size later on, for that reason I created the variable `$index` which is supposed to count the total amount of items in the current list, but instead of continuing to count after one level is completed PHP decides to use the previous iteration before the function was opened recusively.

Code, Output and expexted output below.

**My Question:** Is there a way to iterate the variable `$index` through the whole function?

### PHP Code:

```
<!-- language: php -->
<?php
$lists = [
    [
        'name' => 'level0-item',
        'sub' => [
            ['name' => 'level1-item'],
            ['name' => 'level1-item'],
            ['name' => 'level1-item'],
            [
                'name' => 'level1-item',
                'sub' => [
                    ['name' => 'level2-item'],
                    ['name' => 'level2-item'],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'level1-item',
                'sub' => [
                    ['name' => 'level2-item'],
                    ['name' => 'level2-item'],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],

    [
        'name' => 'level0-item',
        'sub' => [
            ['name' => 'level1-item'],
            ['name' => 'level1-item'],
            ['name' => 'level1-item'],
        ]
    ]
];

function handleLists($lists, $index = 0, $level = 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($lists as $list) {
        echo '<li>';
        $index++; // increas index
        echo $list['name'] . ' - level: ' . $level . ' - index: ' . $index;

        if ($list['sub'])
            handleLists($list['sub'], $index, $level+1); // recursive call
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

handleLists($lists);
?>
```

### Output:

> - level0-item - level: 0 - index: **1**
>
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **2**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **3**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **4**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **5**
>
>     - level2-item - level: 2 - index: **6**
>     - level2-item - level: 2 - index: **7**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **6**
>
>     - level2-item - level: 2 - index: **7**
>     - level2-item - level: 2 - index: **8**
> - level0-item - level: 0 - index: **2**
>
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **3**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **4**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **5**

### Expected output:

> - level0-item - level: 0 - index: **1**
>
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **2**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **3**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **4**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **5**
>
>     - level2-item - level: 2 - index: **6**
>     - level2-item - level: 2 - index: **7**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **8**
>
>     - level2-item - level: 2 - index: **9**
>     - level2-item - level: 2 - index: **10**
> - level0-item - level: 0 - index: **11**
>
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **12**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **13**
>   - level1-item - level: 1 - index: **14**

### Addition

I could have understood nested foreach-/for-loops incorrectly, here is some hopefully understandable pseudocode, i gets increased by 1 every time a new foreach opens.

**Expected behavior:**

i = 0

// step 1
foreach1 opens i = 1

// step 2
foreach1
__foreach2 opens i = 2

// step 3
foreach1
__foreach2
foreach1 opens i = 3

// step 4
foreach1
__foreach2
foreach1
__foreach2 opens i = 4

**Apparent behavior:**

i = 0

// step 1
foreach1 opens i = 1

// step 2
foreach1
foreach1 opens i = 2

// step 3
foreach1
__foreach2 opens i = 2 (cause previous foreach1 i = 1)
foreach1

// step 4
foreach1
__foreach2
foreach1
__foreach2 opens i = 3 (cause previous foreach1 i = 2)

Comment: Your question and example is to hard to understand. Can you make a smaller example? To me your output is the same as the expected output. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Andreas Actually I've reduced my code quite a bit to be easily understandable. But I've highlighted the differences in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to keep track of the actual value of `$index` throughout the whole tree then you could pass it over to `handleLists` as reference (`&index`) instead of a value:

```
function handleLists($lists, &$index = 0, $level = 0) { 
....
}
```

In this way when you are within a recursive call (level 1) and increment `$index`, then this index is also incremented on the first level (level 0) because it's the same variable when you enter a deeper level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as this does work in the simplified PHP example, I haven't found a way to make this work in a Smarty Template I'm extending, if there are no better answers popping up soon I'll definitely accept your answer!